# how to translate this piece of styled-components to css

Tags: css, styled-components

i've just found out about styled-components, could someone translate this code below to plain css?

```
span {
  &:hover {
    & ~ div {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scss to css converter](https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/)

```scss
span {
  &:hover {
    & ~ div {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

the result is

```css
span:hover ~ div {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```